# Can a source generator generate methods with anonymous types as parameters?

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators

Is it possible for a source generator to scan an assembly for used anonymous types, and generate extension methods specifically for those typse?

For example, say you have the following code

```
   var anon = new { Test = 123;}
   anon.SomeExtensionMethod(); // SomeExtensionMethod does not (yet) exist
```

Could a source generator be used to generate `SomeExtensionMethod`?

I've given it a quick try. The name and type information of the anonymous type is available when source generators run. However, their name contains characters invalid in non-compiler generated code, so my attempt led to something like

```
public static class SourceGeneratedCode
{
  public static void SomeExtensionMethod(this global::<anonymous type: int Test> value) { }
}
```

Which of course won't compile. So I wonder - is there any way do to this?

I would like to generate different implementations of this method for different anonymous types; meaning, `SomeExtensionMethod` cannot just take in `object`, or be generic or such.

Comment: Almost always this is an indication that an anonymous type is no longer suitable for use here and you ought to, well, just create an actual type.

Comment: Sure this is possible. A sourcecode-generator just parses your code, so you just need to find a pattern that matches anonymous types.

Comment: But I agree Damien: what's the problem on having non-anonymous types in the first place? When you need are about makling any assumptions on your anonymous types - e.g. this type has an int-property, the other one has two strings - it effectivly turns your types to not so anoynmous ones.

Comment: The general idea would be to source-generate stuff like e.g. javascript's spread operators, which make functional transformations of types quite a bit more convenient. Anonymous types would be a nice starting point for this style of code/operations due to their convenience of defining them inline. Value tuples would _almost_ work as well, if it weren't for the fact their names aren't truly part of their type identity / would get lost in such transformations

Comment: This can be a completely valid design, when method accepts any object and then you want to retrieve the objects fields. Think of passing query params to sql engine, e.g. Dapper. It is very convenient to pass it through an anonymous type instead of creating a new type to use it in a single place in code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this isn't possible, since the generator still has to produce "regular" source code, and there's no way to name an anonymous type.